# Bootstrap apply styles to not required inputs in form.

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I try to validate a form for empty fields with bootstrap.
Required fields are styled correctly when submitting and validating with form.checkValidity() method.
Some fields don't have required attribute but they are styled as correct. 
Why these not required fields checked for validity? Is it normal behavior of bootstrap or is something wrong?

Here is the code i modified from the docs: https://jsfiddle.net/ksilix/v01w3a4h/43/

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="validationCustom01">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="name required" required>
    <div class="valid-feedback">
      Looks good!
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Required!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="validationCustom02">Optional</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Optional">
    <div class="valid-feedback">
      Looks good!
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Required!
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="radio-group1">Optional radio checked</label>
  <div class="form-group" id="radio-group1">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" id="radio1" name="radios1" checked>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">
        Opt1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="2" id="radio2" name="radios1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">
        Opt2
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="radio-group2">Optional radio not checked</label>
  <div class="form-group" id="radio-group2">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" id="radio3" name="radios2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio3">
        Opt3
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="2" id="radio4" name="radios2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio4">
        Opt4
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
  // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
  (function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
      var form = document.getElementById('form1');

      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  })();
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine.

Comment: Not required fields are turning green. i expect them not validated, stay as they are

Comment: https://imgur.com/gb8RCYb

Comment: did you find a solution? having the same issue....

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation any field which looks fine against the validation will be having the `:valid` CSS pseudo-class which in result triggers Bootstrap form styling.

`.was-validated .form-check-input:valid~.form-check-label {...`

Bootstrap suggests own custom validation styling! [Bootstrap Form Validation Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation)

Comment: Okay it is because of :valid class. But why it checks and adds this class to a field which is not required. This did not seemed to me logical. I think i should accept that like this and go on.

Comment: `:valid` CSS pseudo-class is added by `form.checkValidity()` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity) and then Bootstrap styled it